# Toggle button act as radio issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a button which will act as a radio input . Means if there are many buttons only one can be selected at a time .

But as far I created  all buttons are now select-able at a time. I am not able to make how to work this like a radio . I mean only one button . If one is selected other one should be turn off .

any help will be appreciated .

Here is the js fiddle link of what I made till now: http://jsfiddle.net/saifrahu28/eQ744/1/

**HTML**

```
<div style="margin:0px auto; margin-top:100px; width:960px;">
<a href="#">
    <span class="toggleButtonRadio normal">toggle Radio button</span>
</a>


<a href="#">
    <span class="toggleButtonRadio normal">toggle Radio button</span>
</a>


<a href="#">
    <span class="toggleButtonRadio normal">toggle Radio button</span>
</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .toggleButtonRadio , .toggleButton {
  background: #e1e1e1; 
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: .769em;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #454545;
  text-transform: uppercase;
   text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
   border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(64, 64, 64, .5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(64, 64, 64, .5);
  }

  .toggleButtonRadio:hover, .toggleButton:hover{
    background:#d4d4d4;
   }

  .toggleButtonRadio.active , .toggleButton.active{
   background:#90bf00;
   color:#fff;
   }

   .active:hover{
   background:#7ca600;
   }
```

**JS**

```
$('.toggleButtonRadio').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this before the ToggleClass:

```
$('.toggleButtonRadio').removeClass("active");
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/pleasedontbelong/RxXvg/

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `active` class from other buttons, and add the class to current button

```
var $bts = $('.toggleButtonRadio').click(function () {
    $bts.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qMr2e/)